# 1970s-ish science fiction or supernatural book of stories for kids (not a series)

Tags: story-identification

The stories I recall and have been looking for for years may not all be in the same short story collection. I'm not sure. I remember sparse black and white illustrations in what I'm sure was a collection, though not sure all of what I remember came from it. It is probably a book for older elementary or early middle school age. Here is what I recall:

- A girl on a school bus who sees the future and prevents a car wreck
  then later something about a prediction in home economics class where
  a girl gets cake batter on herself.
- A girl no one believes has been
  abducted by aliens until she has an X-ray done and her organs have
  been replaced with mechanical parts.
- A strange man with ill-fitting
  gloves at someone's funeral (narrator's uncle?) and it turns out he
  is alien paying respects to a human friend.
- A boy? who can travel in
  other dimensions, perhaps not always by choice.

I don't think the author(s) would be any big name. Thanks in advance. I've looked so, so long for these!